# How to reach the value behind the childByAutoId()

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key

When I save the projects that the user creates I use the following code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://projectsupport-e475b.firebaseio.com/").child("Projects").childByAutoId() 
let values = ["ProjectTitle": ProjectTitle, "Fighters": EarlySupporters, "Tags": Tags, "TotalFighters": "0", "Description": Description, "ProfileImage": profileImageUrl, "Creator": self.username!] as [String : Any]


ref.updateChildValues(values)
```

This is my database:

```
Projects:
        |
        -------KyHzk8VtHitcLlYw1MT
              | 
              - ProjectName: "ProjectNameTest"
              |
              - Creator: "CreatorTest"
              - And so on...
```

When I try to retrieve the data I use the following code:

```
Database.database().reference().child("Projects").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
            {
                let project = Project(dictionary: dictionary)
                //The following line was the problem:

                //project.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)


                //I'm still not sure why that solved the problem.

                print(project)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

            print(snapshot)
        }, withCancel: nil)
```

This results in a crash as following:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Creator.'

How do I accesses the data? How do I get the key?

[image: ExamleOfProject]

Comment: First on your firebase database did you check if your values are correctly updated as you want ? Then, can you print your dictionnary to see if it retrieves your snapshot values correctly ?

Comment: Like people have mentioned, I think your problem is with your data not firebase

Comment: I'm not to sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

I got it ! I think there is some issue with those lines of code :

`let project = Project(dictionary: dictionary)
project.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)`

**What is the type of your variable project ?** With the `let` keyword in front of it, you are saying that your `project` variable is an **immutable type.** After you set it, you can't modify it. And, it's exactly what you are trying to do on the next line with your function `setValueForKeys`. Try to make `project` as a mutable type with `var project = Project(dictionary: dictionary)` just to see if there is any difference.

Comment: I'm sorry, Xcode says that the variable wasn't changed and is showing an warning, also I save and fetch users with the function with a let statmente.